# Upgrade to 3.3.2 return a blank admin page

Tags: upgrade

When I attempt to upgrade my wordpress site to the latest version (3.3.2) thru the auto update in the dashboard it goes thru the process and at the end says there is an error when the site goes into maintenance mode.  When I reverse all the changes and look for the maintenance file to delete I can't locate it at all.

I then try to do a manual update and I then get a blank screen when attempting to log into the back end of the site.  I also disable all plugins before I attempt to upload updated files.

Any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your host has the minimum versions of php and mysql for 3.3.2? They are PHP version 5.2.4 or greater MySQL version 5.0 or greater.

And: try renaming the plugins folder to old_plugins and see if admin works.

Answer (score 1):

the file is .maintenance so it is hidden. You can view the file via the file explorer under public_html in Cpanel or if you have CLI access look in web root, normally on shared hosting it is public_html folder.

delete the .maintenance file to get out of maintenance mode

Answer (score 0):

What version did you upgrade from?  Wordpress upgrades should be done incrementally in case there are database upgrades, so if you've skipped a major version (like 3.3), you may need to roll back your database and files and upgrade step-by-step.

Also, as markratledge mentioned, rename your plugins folder to old_plugins and see if a plugin failed somewhere along the line.  You might want to set the active theme to twentyeleven in the database as well, in case your theme is using a function that doesn't work anymore.